# facebook chat using ruby gem xmpp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-chat

I want to use facebook chat api, here is my code for sending message.

Code is not showing any error, but the message is not send to my friend in chat.

```
app_id = "2728175525705"
app_secret="72591c4efec0612b42a7f9509c3e"
id = '-my_user_name@chat.facebook.com'
to = '-my_friend_user_name@chat.facebook.com'
body = "hello, Im not spam!"
subject = 'message from ruby'
message = Jabber::Message.new to, body
message.subject = subject

client = Jabber::Client.new Jabber::JID.new(id)
client.connect
client.auth_sasl(Jabber::SASL::XFacebookPlatform.new(client, app_id, 'CAACEdEose0cBAJPkgOTxTraaez71U1yZCaKzukFUyCI5FrLC8xqb0DKHXNEQp9CNkgf2hDGZCXq1FSf52Dc2wc7QcXugmlDFuKA061wZAgO8JEdaHsjK9ceRkOMcH3yDZAKEkInrDL2hgorUshVNTyUZD', app_secret), nil)
client.send message
client.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with userId instead of username?

Comment: why do you put the app_secret in the auth exchange? you shouldn't have to... I'm not familiar with ruby, I use node, so I'm of little help, sorry